# Change the legend's timestamp format in R dygraphs

Tags: r, dygraphs

I'm charting a time series with `dygraphs` in `R` like the following:

```
library(dygraphs)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(data.table)

now <- Sys.time()
dataset <- data.table(time = as.POSIXct(now+1:10),value = 1:10)
d <- dygraph(dataset)
```

The date format displayed in the legend depends in the machine locale and I cannot leave it fixed.

The labels of the x axis can be formatted as follows:

```
valueFormatter<-"function formatValue (ms) {
                return ms.toISOString();
}"

d <- d%>%dyAxis("x", axisLabelFormatter=JS(valueFormatter))
```

However, I don't know how to do it for the legend.

Comment: Two years later, and I'm faced with a similar question. Did you ever manage to format the `dygraph` legend in `R`? `legendFormatter` seems to be the key, but I'm not sure how to include a custom `javascript` formatting function in `dygraphs`.

Comment: @MauritsEvers, I wasn't able to. I even put a bounty on the question. I looked at the JavaScript library back in the day, and my conclusion was that it couldn't be done. I cannot tell you if it has changed since then.

Comment: Thanks for the update. What a pity. My JS is not good enough for me to go down that rabbit hole. I will have another dig around the `dygraphs` GitHub issues and will open a new issue if I can't find a relevant post.

Comment: I am also waiting for date format customisation in dygraphs. Any luck?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to `axisLabelFormatter` there is `legendForamtter`. See for examples:

https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/pull/683
http://dygraphs.com/tests/legend-formatter.html

Comment: This option is not directly available from `R`,  but, I believe it can be somehow replicated using the css and the highlight option. In any case, the example doesn’t deal with timestamps which is what I want to change(it only changes the format for y-axis series).